# How can I place a CodeBuild envrionment variable inside a command parameter?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I have an environment variable for my CodeBuild environment, `DiscordWebhook`. This contains a URL as plaintext. I am trying to run the `sed` command as below. This is specified in the `BuildSpec.yml` file.

```
sed -i 's/discordWebhookAddressLocal/${DiscordWebhook}/g' scripts.js
```

Obviously, this just replaces all instances of `discordWebhookAddressLocal` with "${DiscordWebhook}". I have tried some other methods such as using an `alias` command, but when I try to execute the alias, CodeBuild fails saying that the command could not be found.

How can I specify an environment variable into the command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably happens because you are using **single quotes**. Normally you would use **double quotes** to resolve the variables:

```
sed -i "s/discordWebhookAddressLocal/${DiscordWebhook}/g" scripts.js
```

Comment: When CodeBuild runs this command, it fails with the following error:
`sed: -e expression #1, char 38: unknown option to `s'`

Comment: @AugustWilliams From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705650/sed-unknown-option-to-s-in-bash-script) it seems you have extra slash somewhere. Maybe in the `DiscordWebhook` variable?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple forward slashes in the `DiscordWebhook` address, its a URL endpoint. Do I need to escape them?

Comment: @AugustWilliams Check the link I provided. They give some ideas how to deal with it. It's difficult for me to give more details. But at least `${DiscordWebhook}` resolves now which was your original issue reported.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that there were two separate problems in my case.

First of all, as Marcin has pointed out - double quotes should be used instead of single quotes when using variables. Secondly, the environment variable in question was a URL and had `\` characters in it. This was the same character being used as a delimiter in the `sed` command. To remedy this, I changed the delimiter used in the `sed` command.

The new, complete working command looks like this:

```
sed -i "s|discordWebhookAddressLocal|${DiscordWebhook}|g" scripts.js
```

The commnad now returns no errors at all, and replaces strings inside `scripts.js` as expected.